# hibernate-java8 dependency doesn't help to save date correctly

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data

I have following field declaration:

```
@Entity
public class TransactionStateHistory {
    ...
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
    ...
}
```

and following dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-java8', version: '5.2.10.Final'
```

but in database I see `<binary data>`:
[image]

[image]

Where do I wrong?

Comment: Your column is defined as binary, what do you expect? If it is a dateTime, you should define the column as that

Comment: @Jens as that what?

Comment: As DateTime or samething like that

Comment: You don't need that dependency as with newer versions of Hibernate that is already present in the core. You have to annotate the field with `@Temporal` and specify how you want it stored, else it will be interpreted as a binary field (what is what happend right now).

Comment: @gstackoverflow Looking at your post it looks like you have configure it in a right way. So thats weird, that Hibernate still stores the LocalDateTime as a binary field. Have you recreated/regenerated the database schema after adding the dependency to the 'hibernate-java8' ?

Comment: @Downvoters, what did not you understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From question I see that you are trying to use Hibernate-java8 module instead use `Hibernate-core` 5.2.10.Final as `Hibernate-java8` is merged in Hibernate-core which takes care of converting values to LocalDateTime

Here is the working sample

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LocalDateTimeDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LocalDateTimeDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My entity class

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class DateTimeEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private LocalDateTime localDate;

    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLocalDate()
    {
        return localDate;
    }

    public void setLocalDate(LocalDateTime localDate)
    {
        this.localDate = localDate;
    }

}
```

My repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface LocalDateTimeRep extends JpaRepository<DateTimeEntity, Integer>
{

}
```

Now testing time.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.example.entity.DateTimeEntity;
import com.example.entity.LocalDateTimeRep;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class LocalDateTimeDemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired LocalDateTimeRep repo;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        DateTimeEntity dateTimeEntity = new DateTimeEntity();
        dateTimeEntity.setLocalDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        DateTimeEntity persistedEntry = repo.save(dateTimeEntity);
        System.out.println(persistedEntry.getLocalDate());
    }

}
```

you can persist and retrieve the values of type LocalDateTime without any converts using Hibernate 5.2.10.Final.

Key is the **`POM.XML`**, you need to exclude hibernate-entitymanager from jpa module and in properties set hibernate.version to 5.2.10.Final

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>LocalDateTimeDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>LocalDateTimeDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            **<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>**
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

This way you can use LocalDateTime in springboot and Hibernate.

Comment: bit it doesn't do it

Comment: Are you using spring- boot??

Comment: yep I use spring-boot

Comment: Which version of spring-boot? I will try to get you sample

Comment: springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'

Answer (score 1):

In your main application class (for example MainApplication) could you try to add the following?

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {MainApplication.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class})
```

**Jsr310** is from

> org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten.Jsr310JpaConverters

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that jpa `@Temporal` do not support `java.time` class like LocalDateTime here.

You need to write a converter and set it to automatic bind like this code:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

/**
 * Converter for java.time persistence.
 * 
 * @author m.elbehi
 */
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate date) {


        return date != null ? Date.valueOf(date) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date value) {

        return value != null ? value.toLocalDate() : null;
    }
}
```